# swift: Program-controlled setting of travel times in the calendar is not allowed?

Tags: ios, swift

```
print("travelTime = \(event.value(forKey: "travelTime") as! Double)")
```

`EKCalendarItem`: How do I set the travel time programmatically in the calendar?

With: (1)

```
event.value (forKey: "travelTime") = 900.0
```

or:   (2)

```
event.mutableArrayValue(forKey: "travelTime") = 900.0
```

I just get an error:
(1)

> Expression is not assignable: function call returns immutable value

(2):

> Expression is not assignable: function call returns immutable value

Creating a new event works - but I can't set the travel time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `setValue(_ value: Any?, forKey: String)`:

```
event.setValue(900, forKey: "travelTime")
```

Comment: Thanks (I was probably a bit blind :-))